# Using gglocator() within another function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use gglocator() within a function that looks like this:

```
my_function<- function(point_num) {

 x11()

 iris %>% 
   ggplot()+
     aes(Sepal.Width,Sepal.Length)+
     geom_point()

 points <- gglocator(n = point_num, mercator = FALSE)
    
 return(points)
}
```

which gives me the error: `Error in gglocator(n = point_num, mercator = FALSE) :  ggplot graphic not detected in current device`

It works fine if I do it line by line outside the function.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `ggplot` inside a function doesn't automatically print the produced `ggplot` object the way it does in the console.

Remember that in an interactive session in the console, any object returned by the code you type will be automatically printed: if you type `sum(1:5)` in the console, then the result `[1] 15` is printed to the console. However, if you randomly include the line `sum(1:5)` in the middle of a function, it will have no effect and the result is not printed. The same is true of `ggplot` objects.

So the solution is to wrap your plotting code in an explicit call to `print`:

```r
library(ggmap)

my_function<- function(point_num) {

 x11()

 print(iris %>% 
   ggplot()+
     aes(Sepal.Width,Sepal.Length)+
     geom_point())

 points <- gglocator(n = point_num, mercator = FALSE)

 return(points)
}

my_function(1)

#>   Sepal.Width Sepal.Length
#> 1    2.707581     5.196849
```